# Session 'app': Install failed. In every app including a new one

Tags: android-studio, windows-10

I'm using the latest version of android studio in Windows 10 and at the moment when I run my application the emulator does not connect to the virtual device. Yesterday worked normally and today it does not. Even a new application crash for the same error. The error that comes out is the following:

> cmd package install-create -r -t  -S 1540123' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package'

The event log failure:

> 5:39 PM    Session 'app': Install failed.
>                   Installation failed
>                   Rerun

And the Logcat shows the following:

> 2019-07-02 10:30:03.128 19277-19277/? E/hostapd: hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
>
> 2019-07-02 10:30:03.950 19282-19282/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to get interface flags for wlan1: No such device
>
> 2019-07-02 10:30:04.884 19285-19286/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x70 in tid 19286 (Binder:19285_1), pid 19285 (cmd)
>
> 2019-07-02 10:30:04.923 19288-19288/? A/crash_dump32: crash_dump.cpp:246] target died before we could attach (received main tid = 19286)
>   2019-07-02 10:30:04.926 1556-1556/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 1
>
> 2019-07-02 10:30:08.137 19301-19301/? E/hostapd: Configuration file: /vendor/etc/simulated_hostapd.conf
>
> 2019-07-02 10:30:08.140 19301-19301/? E/hostapd: Could not read interface wlan1 flags: No such device
>
> 2019-07-02 10:30:08.142 19301-19301/? E/hostapd: nl80211 driver initialization failed.

I dont have any idea about whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

create a new device solved the problem for me.